# How to hide views UI reaching number of limits of searches

Tags: 8, views

I'm developing a D8 site. I am using a custom views plugin to query data from a remote api by searching a business ID.

My scenario: User is only allowed to enter 3 attempts of business ID in a search view. If 3 attempts fails, I want to hide the views UI from the page for 24 hours. What's my purpose? To give difficulty for others to guess my business ID.

This is a duplicate question with: [How to use Rules to limit the number of searches to pull data from a remote API](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228540/how-to-use-rules-to-limit-the-number-of-searches-to-pull-data-from-a-remote-api), but on another perspective.

I wasn't able to implement it using Rules, and I'm guessing if we can do it on front-end coding. Does anyone have an idea to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can Set a configuration variable for each user (it's equal variables on drupal 7 ) and for each search increase it,reset it each day,**But** another and simple method is  implement it by `cookie` , create a cookie for user, set expire to 24 hours, and every time user search, first check it's cookie and if not do it more that three times  show results for him/her else  there is nothing to him/her.I think cookie solution is good for you.